# How to serve the same static files regardless of the route?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, koa, koa-router

I have a react App. With webpack I build for production. Now I try to set a little koa server to serve the static files generated by webpack for production.

So I did this

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import serve from 'koa-static'

const app = new Koa()

app.use(serve('dist/'))

app.listen(3001)
```

Where `dist/` is the directory where are the files (index.html, bundle etc).
This works well but only for the route '/' (localhost:3001/)
In my app I use react router so I need to go to /login (localhost:3001/login) by example. But when I try I get "Not Found". With the devServer (by webpack) this route works well. I just need to always serve /dist, whatever the route. How to do this whit koa ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally won

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import serve from 'koa-static'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

const app = new Koa()
const dist = path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
let validRoutes

fs.readdir(dist, (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err)
  validRoutes = files
})

function isRouteValid (url) {
  if (!validRoutes || !url) return false
  return validRoutes.find(route => url.slice(1) === route)
}

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  if (!isRouteValid(ctx.url)) ctx.path = 'index.html'
  await next()
})

app.use(serve(dist))

app.listen(3010)
```

Answer (score 6):

One option is to intercept the react-router client routes in Koa and rewrite them to '/' to load index.html and the client assets.

```
const REACT_ROUTER_PATHS = [
  '/login',
  '/logout',
  '/other-client-path'
];

app
  .use(async (ctx, next) => {
    if (REACT_ROUTER_PATHS.includes(ctx.request.path)) {
      ctx.request.path = '/';
    }
    await next();
  })
  .use(serve('dist/'));
```

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

Comment: Can you share the error stack trace? Is it on the client or from the Koa service?

Answer (score 3):

If koa is like `express-static` it is normal that he returns 'Not Found' because the only file present is 'index.html'.
My solution

```
import fs from 'fs';


app.use(serve('dist/'));
// If the file is not found by koa
// intercept all request and return index.html
// this way you can manage the request in React 
app.use((ctx, next) => {
    ctx.type = 'html';
    ctx.body = fs.readFileSync('./dist/index.html');
});
```

Comment: I get `server error TypeError: ctx.res.sendFile is not a function`

Comment: Sorry I was new to Koa! I use Express! I updated my code!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your build is generated, just looking at the files in that generated `dist` directory might not be enough. If you're using CRA for example, you'll probably need something more like what they use [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5827895/9107546) to find all valid routes in children directories too. So you might have something that looks like

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import serve from 'koa-static';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const app = new Koa();
const dist = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
let validRoutes;

var walk = function(dir, done) {
    var results = [];
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        var i = 0;
        (function next() {
            var file = list[i++];
            if (!file) return done(null, results);
            file = path.resolve(dir, file);
            fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
                if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                    walk(file, function(err, res) {
                        results = results.concat(res);
                        next();
                    });
                } else {
                    results.push(file);
                    next();
                }
           });
        })();
    });
};

walk(dist, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    validRoutes = results;
});

function isRouteValid (r: string) {
    if (!validRoutes || !r) return false;
    return validRoutes.find(route => r === route);
}

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    if (!isRouteValid(path.resolve(dist, ctx.url.slice(1)))) ctx.path = 'index.html';
    await next();
});

app.use(serve(dist));

app.listen(3010);
```